# Set weight of edges in routing graph of skobbler sdk

Tags: android, skmaps

I want to use OpenStreetMap and Skobbler SDK for an Android App providing route navigation. Can I manipulate the weight if edges in routing Graphs of Skobbler SDK? I've looked up in the online documentation and reference but I didn't find anything related to weights of graph edges.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

You cannot easily do this. Some possible alternatives:

- if the weights are "static" (not changing during runs) - you can build a custom routing profile with the help of the Telenav/skobbler team (it depends on what exactly you want to change, it might be that you can modify an already existing routing profile or you would need a new one)
- if you want "dynamic" weights - you can model this as a traffic server - exposing your dynamic weights in [OpenLR format](http://www.openlr.org/) would allow the SDK to read this information at run time (this might also require some integration work in the SDK so check directly with their team). This is definitely possible as the SDK already has traffic information integrated

Comment: Thanks alot. What about using the method
    `SKRouteInfo.setDistance(int distance)`and set the distance to a high value when I want to set up a high weight?

Comment: Won't work - you need to set weights on specific segments or roads before the actual route is calculated

Comment: Does the skobbler SDK speak OpenLR?

Comment: It understands a traffic server that speaks OpenLR